# How to prevent Excel Add-In file from changing cell references to R1C1/columns to letters

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, add-in

I created an Excel Add-In file (`.xlam`) to be able to distribute my macro the my department. However, I'm faced with an issue that I can't seem to find when I search the web for answers. When I add and install the Add-In file to Excel (via vbscript, if that matters) it sets Excel to R1C1 mode, so the columns are numbered instead of lettered. Any idea what might be causing this? Could it something in the vbscript or Add-In files that trigger this change? Has anyone ever had this happen to them before when deploying an Add-In for Excel? How do I prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it appears I found the *actual* solution from [this link](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=72357), where Post #10 on that forum thread points to Tip 2 in [this link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/StartupErrors.aspx).

The steps are as follows:

1. Exit Excel (After adding the Add-In)
2. Click Start > Run > Enter `Excel.exe /UnregServer`
3. Wait for Excel to finish opening again
4. Exit Excel (again),
5. Click Start > Run > Enter `Excel.exe /RegServer`

What this does is cleans (un-registers & re-registers) the registry. I hope this will save even one person the hours of googling and forum surfing that it took me to finally stumble upon the *actual* solution, instead of just a workaround.

**Update to include VBScript Implementation Example:**

To accomplish the above steps using VBScript (below script adapted from [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1650078)), you can use code similar to this (changing your path to your Excel.exe of course)

```
Dim objFSO, objShell
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell")
objShell.Run "cmd /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\excel.exe"" /unregserver && timeout /t 3 && tskill excel && ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\excel.exe"" /regserver",1,True
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
x=msgbox("Excel registry refreshed." ,0, "Registry Update")
wscript.quit
```

> ### Disclaimer:
>
> As @Rory points out below (see link in his comment), according to Microsoft's documentation those switches don't work from versions dated 2010 on. Though there are many instances of people citing that they have used this method with 2010 or later versions with success (see links in my comments) I figured I would just make whoever is reading this aware that it is a now-unsupported method by Microsoft. However, if it works for you and your situation (as many unsupported features of Microsoft often do) feel free to still use it.

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? Those switches are supposed to be non-functional from 2007 onward.

Comment: 2010, works like a charm. I'm about to update my answer with an example of how to carry out this action with vbscript code.

Comment: That's very interesting as this MSKB article specifically states that those switches don't work from 2010 on (I misspoke earlier): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291288 and I've been told the same by the product team before.

Comment: Now I'm very intrigued as well. I certainly hear what you're saying, but it's perplexing how there are many examples on the web of others using this method with 2007, 2010, 2013, (the one that jumps out the most is this [Microsoft Forum Answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/problems-with-versions-of-office-2010/69ae700c-c659-41c0-9848-edbd9b087436)). Odd. I too am now very curious about the workings of this. Maybe it's just not "supported" by Microsoft anymore? Like many other "unsupported" commands, they often still work.

Comment: I was told it doesn't do anything. (I'm a little sceptical about answers in Answers since you never know who actually marked it as an answer.)

Comment: True, but I'm left perplexed as to why this resolved my issue when I ran the script above then. I found another answer on the Microsoft Forum ([here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_365hp-excel/excel-2013/b9c48d04-5656-405b-817e-3d1e42bcbe9a)) offering the same advice. But, as per your previous comment, I understand why one should be skeptical of answers on the Answers forum. That being said, I'm at a loss now. Advice?

Comment: Accept it worked and move on! :) It confuses me since registry settings are not workbook specific (unless the workbook changes them in code) so I can't see why it would help, whether the switch worked or not!

Comment: I'll do just that then! I also added a disclaimer to my answer citing your link. Thanks for helping point that out! :)

Answer (score 4):

Try to look if you changing `Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1`

If not, i would try to insert

```
Dim previousRefStyle
previousRefStyle = Application.ReferenceStyle
Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
```

and on the begining

```
Application.ReferenceStyle = previousRefStyle
```

So user will have restored original settings

Comment: I didn't find any references to `Application.ReferenceStyle` (either in my modules or ThisWorkbook, but adding the suggested `Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1` to the Workbook_Open Event did the trick, thanks! I'm still curious though as to what might be causing this issue in the first place. There has to be something in the vba code causing it because if I open the file with macros disabled this doesn't happen. Weird.

Comment: MS is all about magic. So expect some little troll hiden in sheet, and without proper witchcraft you arent able to banish it :(

Comment: Haha I'm well aware of MS's witchcraft by now. I'll continue to do some digging for a bit and if nothing else jumps out I'll award your workaround as the answer. Thanks again!